# I cant break blocks in minecraft but I can place them and do other things

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My little brother was fooling around with the keys and I cant get it to break blocks. I can place blocks and perform other tasks.  I tried everything in settings but it just wont break blocks.

If anyone can explain how to fix this that would be great because right now I am totally MineCraftless and I need to play that game!!!!

Thank You

Comment: What do you mean by keys? Bindings, which would make swiftsly's answer correct, or was he typing commands into chat?

Comment: punctuation is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your **Attack/Destroy** button in the "*Options*," "*Controls*" settings menu is set to the correct button, usually the left mouse button (Button 1).  If not, click the button across from **Attack/Destroy** and then click the assignment button with your left mouse button.

Now, go into a world try holding down the left mouse button and you should be able to break blocks.